# Preimage of subgroup $H \subseteq G/N$ has order $|H| \cdot |N|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Finite group $G$ has normal subgroup $N$, with $H$ a subgroup of $G/N$.

$\varphi : G \rightarrow G/N$ represents the natural map $\varphi (g) = gN$.

I'm trying to show that the preimage of $H$ under $\varphi$ has order $|H| \cdot |N|$.

Intuitively, I can make sense of this, since $H$ contains $|H|$ cosets, each of which contains $|N|$ elements of G. And it seems like each element that is in one of the cosets of H is in $\varphi^{-1} (H)$. I'm having trouble proving this however. Here is what I've been trying:

Let $a \in gN$ for some $gN \in H$, i.e. let $a$ be an element in one of the cosets in $H$.

Then this should somehow lead to $aN = \varphi (a) \in H \Longrightarrow a \in \varphi^{-1}(H)$

Since all cosets are disjoint, and there are total $|H| \cdot |N|$ elements contained in the cosets in $H$, then that would be the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H'=\varphi^{-1}[H]$ and note $\ker(\varphi)=\varphi^{-1}[\{N\}]\subseteq H'$. Now, $\varphi|_{H'}$ is a group epimorphism from $H'$ to $H$ with $\ker(\varphi|_{H'})=H'\cap\ker(\varphi)=\ker(\varphi)=N$ and therefore $$\frac{H'}{N}\approx H$$ which yields $\frac{|H'|}{|N|}=|H|$ and thus $|H'|=|H||N|$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: two cosets are either disjoint or equal, so if $a\in gN$, what can you say about $aN$?

Answer (score 1):

The map $\varphi$ is $|N|$ to $1$, since the kernel has order $|N|$.

Then since $\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(H))=H$, the conclusion follows.